v-text-field adding margin at bottom on runtime, when validation fails
```<v-text-field color="primary" class="hello" v-model="form.name" label="Name" placeholder="Name" variant="outlined" hide-details="auto" density="compact" :rules="[rules.required]">
</v-text-field>```

This adds margin at bottom on runtime, when validation fails... and removes it when validation passes...
this give a bit of transition to form. Can we keep the mb consistent so it do not move up and down.. on validation pass or fail.

Remove hide-details="auto" should solve you issues.
<v-text-field color="primary" class="hello" v-model="form.name" label="Name" placeholder="Name" variant="outlined"  density="compact" :rules="[rules.required]">
</v-text-field>


Just add these styles to resolve the issue in vuetify 3.
<style scoped lang="css">
.left-alignment {
    margin-left: 119px
}

.text-field-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 62px;
    /* Adjust based on your design */
}


.v-input__control {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.v-messages {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

